# What is the best way to store array of characters in django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.7

I have an array of MAC addresses. How do I store them in Django 1.7 model? My code is:

```
MAC=models.CharField(max_length = 20,null=True,blank=True)
```

I have to store different MAC address for a single user

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your usage. I'm going to guess that you want to assign a variable number of MAC addresses to some other model and each MAC address can only be used once.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    pass

class MacAddress(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='mac_addresses')
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 20,null=True,blank=True, unique=True)
```

So for each address in your array, you'd create a new instance of `MacAddress`

Comment: I have to store different MAC address for a single user

Comment: how do i create for each address in your array, you'd create a new instance of MacAddress ?

Comment: Yes. ```MacAddress``` is just another model in my example. You could use ```bulk_create``` or a for loop with ```MacAddress.objects.create```.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a ManyToMany Field.

My models.py

```
class MacAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 20,null=True,blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.address

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True,db_index=True)
    MAC=models.ManyToManyField(MacAddress)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
mac = get_mac()
            mac = (hex(mac))
            MacAdd=MacAddress()
            MacAdd.address=mac
            MacAdd.save()
            profile.save()
            profile.MAC.add(MacAdd)
            profile.save()
```